# Why are my web references betting published from Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When publishing a web app in VS 2010, (soap) web references we're never published.  However, in VS 2012, the datasource items Build Action are marked as Content instead of None by default.  Updating a web-reference tends to flip this for existing ones as well, so I have a mixed bag now where some are Content and some are None.  It's annoying to go flip this manually each time, and having my team do that is just silly.  They don't seem to be needed in the publish, so I'm unsure why this is happening.  This is noise every time we publish.

Does anyone know if this is a bug in VS2012, or there's some setting somewhere to modify the default behavior of what these files get added as?